# How to click browser "Stop" button using WatiN

Tags: c#, watin

I'm clicking the link on some page and it opens in new tab. But that website loads not fast and has some flash animations and some other elements that load for long time. But all necessary info for me loads at once. So I need to make page stop loading. Browser "Stop" button will do well. Can I access it using WatiN?? Or is there some other way to solve my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using httpwebrequest/webresponse? it should get only the page without any other elements (no css no images no flash animations) - just the page's code and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
private void GetPage(string protocol, string address, string extraPath, string[][] postData)
{
      try
      {
           long length = 0;
           string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(protocol + address + extraPath);
            httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            httpWebRequest2.Host = address;
            httpWebRequest2.Referer = protocol + address;
            httpWebRequest2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30";
            httpWebRequest2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
            httpWebRequest2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pt-PT;q=0.2,en-GB;q=0.2");
            httpWebRequest2.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(boundary + "\r\n");
            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            length += boundarybytes.Length;
            boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            length += boundarybytes.Length;

            // Send any data via POST that you might need
            for (int i = 0; i < postData.length; i++;
            {
                 string head = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + postData[i][0] + "\"\r\n\r\n";
                 byte[] headbytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(head);
                 memStream.Write(headbytes, 0, headbytes.Length);
                 length += headbytes.Length;
                 head = postData[i][1];
                 headbytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(head);
                 memStream.Write(headbytes, 0, headbytes.Length);
                 length += headbytes.Length;
                 memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                 length += boundarybytes.Length;
            }

            httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
            Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            memStream.Close();
            requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2, Encoding.UTF8);
            string htmlpage = reader2.ReadToEnd();
            reader2.Close();
            webResponse2.Close();
            httpWebRequest2 = null;
            webResponse2 = null;
            // At this point, htmlpage contains all the code from the page ready to be handled
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    // Got an error page from the server so save it and show it on browser
                    Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2, Encoding.UTF7);
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("error.html");
                    writer.Write(reader2.ReadToEnd());
                    writer.Close();
                    reader2.Close();
                    response.Close();
                    response = null;
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("error.html");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Call it in this way:

```
GetPage("http://", "www.google.com", "/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=stackoverflow", new strin[] {new string[]}); // in this case i send no data for post
```

Comment: This is a rather complex example of use - but since i had no clue on the particulars of your needs i placed it all - you might not need some of that depending on your needs - hope it helps

Comment: Actually i need another stuff. When my page loads completely it launches javascript. And i need this javascript to work. But this page loads very slow and sometimes freezes. So javascript doesnt start. When i press Stop button in browser it launches that javascript. It's exactly what i need. Do u have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: well, unless the javascript is on a separate file (not in the html page under a <script> tag) the above should do it - just copy what is done there with error page on catch and apply that to the htmlpage variable's content. If, however, the javascript is external to the page, then you will have to get the javascript file too (same method) place it according to its location on the site - save the page in the same way then run the page (as with the error message)

Comment: of course that assumes the webssite will allow you to download tha javascript file - wich isn't always the case

Comment: i tried that for a while but it seemed a bit complicated for me. But i found solution. I downloaded AdBlock Plus extension for firefox and created some rules. So it blockes me all content and leaves just frame which i need. But nevertheless thanks for ur replies.

Comment: Glad you have yourself a solution